# unexpected javascript date behavior

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var newDate=new Date('05/22/2012');
var month=newDate.getMonth();
var day=newDate.getDate()+(-2);
var year=newDate.getYear();
document.write(month+'/'+day+'/'+year);
```

I expected it to return '05/20/2012' but instead it returns '04/20/2012'

This makes no sense to me - can someone help me understand what's going on and how to get the correct response?

Thank you for your kind attention!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.getMonth()` is zero-based. as in `0=January` and `11=December`

try

```
var month=newDate.getMonth() + 1;
```

Answer (score 7):

[`.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) is zero-based. January corresponds to 0, February to 1, etc.

As of the time of this question, the month is May, and therefore `.getMonth()` returns `4`.

You want `.getMonth() + 1`.

Comment: and THANK YOU! I marked the previous as the answer only because it was first - obviously yours is just as valid!

Comment: @Dutchie432: Ditto! jlisham: You're welcome - I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score -1):

```
getMonth() + 1
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question?