# Issue using Date() in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

Anyone can tell me why if I type this:

```
var datedate1 = new Date(2017, 05, 17);
console.log(datedate1);
```

The console shows: `2017-06-16T22:00:00.000Z`?

Thank you.

Comment: Because you ignored two well known facts; first that the month is counted from 0 to 11, and secondly that time zones exist.

Comment: See [*unexpected javascript date behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706272/unexpected-javascript-date-behavior) or [*setDate() unexpected behaviour wrong month*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146897/javascript-setdate-unexpected-behaviour-wrong-month), there are a lot of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here:

1. Month is 0-indexed, to get 5 you need to pass through 04 for the month
2. The date used uses UTC time prior to localising to your timezone(GMT-2)? so you will need to account for your timezone and pass through those arguements.

Another option is to look at using a framework like moment 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Comment: Re "*The date used uses UTC time prior to localising to your timezone*" The host time zone offset is used to generate the Date in the first place, the issue here is that the output timezone is UTC+00:00. *toString* will typically use local. I wouldn't call moment.js a "framework", it's a library (i.e. a bundle of useful functions).