# How to get Month from given Date using date-fns

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

Please help to get right month from given dates. I spent allot of hours, and almost stuck..

Here is a function:

So the task is to check if month and year is equal to given dates. If dateLeft is empty, make comparison between 1970-01-01 and given date.

**I'm using a getMonth function from date-fns** for getting Month

```
import { parseISO, format, getMonth, getYear } from 'date-fns'
import ru from 'date-fns/locale/ru'

const ifMonthAndYearIsEqual = (dateLeft, dateRight) => {
  const date1 = dateLeft ? new Date(dateLeft.seconds * 1000) : new Date(1970, 1, 1)
  const date2 = new Date(dateRight.seconds * 1000)

  console.log("TCL: ifMonthAndYearIsEqual -> dateLeft", dateLeft)
  console.log("TCL: ifMonthAndYearIsEqual -> dateRight", dateRight)
  console.log("TCL: ifMonthAndYearIsEqual -> date1", date1)
  console.log("TCL: ifMonthAndYearIsEqual -> date2", date2)

  console.log("TCL: ifMonthAndYearIsEqual -> getMonth(date1)", getMonth(date1))
  console.log("TCL: ifMonthAndYearIsEqual -> getMonth(date2)", getMonth(date2))

  const monthIsEqual = (getMonth(date1) === getMonth(date2))
  console.log(monthIsEqual)
}

export default ifMonthAndYearIsEqual
```

**date.Right** i'm getting from firebase. This is a timestamp object, that has seconds and nanoseconds.

In my case, i'm always have for `console.log(getMonth(date2))` 0, but givet date is **1579254008** in seconds. What's wrong?

**UPDATE**
Consol logs:
[image]

Comment: you are getting console.log(getMonth(date1)) and date2 right successfully right ??

Comment: Did you declare `var getMonth = require('date-fns/getMonth')`? Also, what format are your date parameters?

Comment: i've updated my post with consol logs and whole code of my file

Comment: @PaulS updated clg to be more clear

Comment: Looks like the date is returned correctly now isn't it?

Comment: @PaulS but January is 1 month of the year, so getMonth(date1) must return 1, and date 2 must also return 1 . Why getMoths begin from 0?

Comment: Could you show where you create dateLeft and dateRight?

Comment: const check = ifMonthAndYearIsEqual('', creationDate). creationDate is a timestamp from firestore. i have all consol.logs in my post what it is exactly

Comment: Oh, i think the reason is in the date-fns library:
in date-fns, as in JavaScript standard library 0 means January, 6 is July and 11 is December:
new Date(2018, 0, 1) //=> 1st of January
new Date().getMonth() //=> 6

Comment: ECMAScript months are zero based (just like Java and many other languages). Assuming 1579254008 represents seconds offset from the common epoch of 1 Jan 1970, it represents 2020-01-17T09:40:08.000Z, so `new Date(1579254008 * 1000).getMonth()` returns `0` for January. Also see [*unexpected javascript date behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706272/unexpected-javascript-date-behavior).